# External access to Ubuntu single-node openstack horizon dashboard

Tags: networking, openstack, iptables

I successfully installed OpenStack on spare server using the Ubuntu single-node installer script. The OpenStack status page on the underlying Ubuntu instance is green across the board. From the host Ubuntu instance I can ping / ssh to all of the various OpenStack instances which have been started on the virtual network.

I now want to access the horizon dashboard from my pc on the local network  (I can't access it from the host Ubuntu machine since it is a server install & thus has no desktop to run a web browser on).  My local network is 192.168.1.xxx, with the ubuntu server having a static IP of 192.168.1.200. Horizon was installed on an instance with IP 10.0.4.77.

Based on the blog post [Installing Ubuntu OpenStack on a Single Machine, Instead of 7](http://serenity-networks.com/installing-ubuntu-openstack-on-a-single-machine-instead-of-7/), it looks like I need to make an iptables change to the host Ubuntu instance to bridge between the two networks. The suggested command from the blog post above is:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.250 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.6.241:443
```

Which if I modify for my network / install would be:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.4.77:443
```

However, I am suspicious this is not the preferred way to do this.  First, because the `--dport 8000` seems wrong, and second because I was under the impression that neutron should be used to create the necessary bridge.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just access the dashboard from your laptop you can use sshuttle:

```
sshuttle ubuntu@<server_ip> -r 10.0.6.0/24
```

That'll let you load up your dashboard with the container IP. If you want something more substantial then configuring iptables is probably the way to go.